# Can I scrape a website's JavaScript Debugger Console data?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, scrape, javascript-debugger, uptime-monitoring

I use Pingdom Uptime Monitor to make sure my website is alive and well
It works great

I also want to make sure that I keep a clean and empty JS console on my site.
If it's not empty, it means something has likely gone wrong, and I need to investigate. I want to be alerted when something appears in my JS console, without checking manually.

I haven't found any info on how to make a GET request to receive a website's JS Console debugger info (don't need the website's HTML, JS, or CSS)

This could also easily be rolled into a SaaS. Thanks.

Comment: Well I mean, all console output is is the output from your program. So if you are expecting something there, you should rewrite your actual code to log the errors or messages to somewhere and then execute a request off of that. There isn't a magic API endpoint that says give me my output.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Maybe you can have a look on how to ask good questions on stackoverflow here:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

You can use puppeteer the headless chrome browser which will give you full access to browser console via api too, please refer to the docs here:
https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.11.0&show=api-event-console

Answer (score 1):

The JS console output doesn't come from the server; you can't get it with an HTTP request.  Console output is produced by the page's scripts running in the browser, and the only way to get it is by loading the page and running its scripts like a browser would.  [PhantomJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhantomJS) *might* help for that.

Answer (score 1):

A headless browser might be a perfect solution for this problem. Personally I would recommend Google Puppeteer.

Solution can be as easy as:

```
page.on('console', msg => {
  for (let i = 0; i < msg.args().length; ++i)
    console.log(`${i}: ${msg.args()[i]}`);
});
page.evaluate(() => console.log('hello', 5, {foo: 'bar'}));
```

Please refer to **[docs](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.11.0&show=api-event-console)**.

Comment: thank you to all responders for clarifying this for me.